# Taylor series expansion of cos(x) is not working

Tags: c, math, trigonometry, logic-error

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#define PI 3.1416
double fact(n){
  double x = 1;
  for(int i = 1 ; i <= n ; i++){
    x = x*i;
  }
  return x;
}
int main(void) {
  int deg,term,n=1,sign=1;
  float radian,result=0;
  printf("Enter the Angle (in degree) : ");
  scanf("%d",&deg);
  printf("Enter the number of terms : ");
  scanf("%d",&term);
  radian = deg*(PI/180.0);

  for(int count = 0 ;n<=term ; count+=2){
    result = result + sign *(double)(pow(radian,count)/fact(count));
    n++;
    sign = sign * (-1) ;
  }
  
  printf("user defined cos(%d) = %f\n",deg,result);
  printf("inbuilt cos(%d) = %f\n",deg,cos(deg));
  return 0;
}
```

I tried similar code with sin function and with different value for count but its not working for cos. If anybody knows why its printing wrong answer... please reply

Comment: What do you mean by "not working"? Doesn't it build? Does it crash? Does it give wrong results? Please [edit] your question to add more details. Also please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: OT: Don't use `float` unless you have a very good reason... Here there doesn't seem to be a good reason so change `float` to `double`

Comment: Do not use `pow()` for computing small integer powers.  Simple multiplication is faster and sometimes more precise.

Comment: You can avoid `pow()` and `fact()` by using a 'working term' that you multiply by the angle and divide by the count in each iteration.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is right, your test is wrong:

Instead of `cos(deg)`, it should be `cos(radian)`.

Moreover, instead of defining `PI`, you could use the one given in `math.h`: `M_PI`:

```
#define _USE_MATH_DEFINES
#include <math.h>

// from here, you can use M_PI
```

---

You can also improve your code

1. Since cosine function is periodic and the Taylor series is better near 0, you should clamp the input number in [-180, 180] range
2. Factorial function could be computed faster: you have to compute 2!, 4!, 6!... if you store 4! for instance, 6! can be computed with only 2 multiplications instead or recomputing from the start (like you do for `sign` instead of calling `pow(-1, n)`
3. Same for the `x^(2n)`

Comment: Some implementations provide `M_PI`, but the C language specifications say nothing about it.  I think that's a good enough reason to provide one's own `PI`, but a more precise value than appears in the OP's code would certainly be in order.

Comment: Minor edit applied: I assume a range is specified with `[]` rather than with `]]` - apologies if there is some esoteric notation I am not familiar with!

Answer (score -1):

Your code is inefficient.  You call factorial over and over without memoizing it.

Here are better examples in Python.  No calls to a factorial function needed.  You should be able to port them.

```
def cosine(t, n):
    result = 0.0
    term = 1.0
    sign = 1.0
    for i in range(0, n):
        result += sign*term
        sign *= -1.0
        term *= t*t/(2*i+1)/(2*i+2)
    return result

def sine(t, n):
    result = 0.0
    term = t
    sign = 1.0
    for i in range(1, n):
        result += sign*term
        sign *= -1.0
        term *= t*t/(2*i)/(2*i+1)
    return result
```